# Background worker not updating main form richtextbox and textbox

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to send a string to a richtextbox via a background worker to update the control on the main form.

I am receiving data from a serial port from another class/thread and calling a public method on the main form that starts the background worker.

The background worker starts but fails to update the richtextbox but does show the messagebox with the correct serial data.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public WithEvents RichTextBox2 As RichTextBox
    Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Public WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox

    Public Serial_txt As String

    Public Sub Display_Serial_Data_In(ByVal txt As String)
        Serial_txt = txt

        If Me.BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() : MsgBox("Running Worker Proccess")

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.RichTextBox2.AppendText(Serial_txt)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Serial_txt
        MsgBox(Serial_Txt, vbOKOnly, "Worker Complete")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you actually have a DoWork method runnning?

Comment: I tried putting the Richtextbox.appendtext in the DoWork method and it fails but if a put a Messagebox in the DoWork it displays the serial text fine, I am not getting any exceptions at all, it seems to allow dialogbox calls but ignore calls to update form controls.

Comment: Bottom line is, you can't access GUI controls from a non-GUI thread, and that's what you are doing with your rtb.AppendText code.  The DoWork method is *only* for handling long running processes.  Sounds like you need to read up on the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) component.